# Snowflake stored procedures and transactions: unclear documentation?

Tags: transactions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The Snowflake docs (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html) have some seemingly contradictory information about stored procedures and transactions: On the one hand: "If a stored procedure is called outside an explicit transaction, then each statement inside the stored procedure executes as a separate transaction." On the other: "Currently, transaction control commands (BEGIN, COMMIT, ROLLBACK) are not allowed inside a stored procedure. This means that a stored procedure is executed entirely within a single transaction (explicitly or implicitly)." Which of the two is it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just calling the stored procedure, it's not explicitly in a transaction. Each operation will be visible as it completes..

If you start a transaction and call a stored procedure it's in a transaction, and as long as you do not do any DDL that breaks snowflake transactions, you are atomic.

That how we read/understand it.

The docs say what I said:

> If a stored procedure is called outside an explicit transaction, then each statement inside the stored procedure executes as a separate transaction.

this is the part that explains where the explicit/ implicit part comes from

> Remember that DDL statements (CREATE TABLE, etc.) cause an implicit COMMIT. Such statements should not be used inside a stored procedure if the procedure will be called inside a transaction. For example, the following pseudo-code demonstrates what not to do:

this part is explaining the reason transactions are broken

> Currently, transaction control commands (BEGIN, COMMIT, ROLLBACK) are not allowed inside a stored procedure. This means that a stored procedure is executed entirely within a single transaction (explicitly or implicitly).

Thus this part is referring to those other parts. It's effectively says you cannot do nested/recursive transactions. Like you can in other DBs.

Comment: That makes sense... so it's that "(explicity or implicitly)" in the docs that confuses me.

Comment: I tried to add more words, to tie it together, it just makes sense to me, (it's not really good English, so that might the cause..) if you could explain what aspect is feeling odd/strange.

Comment: If I create a temporary table inside a stored procedure, will it cause an implicit COMMIT?